# JQuery datePicker Highlight color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I used the below theme for datepicker and i need to custom a color change.
I need to have a change in color when i select a new date.

Example: Need to have 25 Oct in custom color since it is already been selected.

Thanks

Comment: "the below theme"? And what have you tried? This is not a "plz make my code" site.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these css to your page since `ui-state-active` is the style of the date you select and `ui-state-highlight` is the style it uses to identify the current date.

```
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-state-active {color: #FFFFCC;}

#ui-datepicker-div .ui-state-highlight {color: #DCDCDC;}
```